# Forte Hosted Form callback in vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have used Forte Hosted Form for making payment in our ASP.NET project. Currently I need to do the same in vue.js. I am able to open the Forte Hosted Form but I am not getting the response.
Forte provide  a callback attribute for its html5 button. Which capture the payment response. But I am not able to capture response using that callback attribute.

Here is my code:

```html
<button
    callback="oncallback"
    :api_access_id=“forteRequestModel.apiAccessID”  
    version_number ="2.0"...>
    Make Payment
</button>
```

JS Code :

```
methods :{
   oncallback: function(e){
       alert("Hello " + e.response);
  }
```

}

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine this works by assuming that the named function given to `callback` is available globally.

You can have your Vue component create the callback function on the `window` object so that it is available globally. For example

```html
<button
    :callback="callbackFunctionName"
    :api_access_id="forteRequestModel.apiAccessID"
    version_number ="2.0"...>
    Make Payment
</button>
```

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    forteRequestModel: {
      apiAccessID: "whatever"
    },
    callbackFunctionName: `cb${Date.now()}` // generate a unique function name
  }),
  created () {
    // register the callback on `window`
    window[this.callbackFunctionName] = (e) => {
      alert("Hello " + e.response)

      // this could also call component methods, access data, props, etc
    }
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    delete window[this.callbackFunctionName] // cleanup
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new in vue. So one question.  Can you please tell me why we need to generate a unique function name?

Comment: You don't really have to but it might help with any duplicate component conflicts